# Is there a limitation on number of wav files opened in mbed?

Tags: c++, mbed, lpc

I have an application where I want to open up to 27 different .wav files on an ARM MBED LPC1768, for eventual output on a codec board.  Currently I have been able to open and play files on the mbed (the files are stored on a micro-sd card).   However I am having an issue opening more than 11 files at once.

The call I am using to open any given file is like so:

```
FILE* mywav1 = fopen("/sd/mydir/SoundDecoder_second/01.wav","rb");
```

I have performed tests where, if I attempt to open, say, 20  files in this manner, I will test each open with:

```
        if(mywav1 == NULL){
            printf("Cannot Open mywav1\n\r");
        }
```

I can only open up 11 files, the other 9 will return NULL.

I have checked and this isn't anything to do with naming conventions as far as I can see - it is all to do with the number of files that can physically be opened in separate filestreams.

Is there some limit as to how many files that can be opened in a file stream at once in the mbed sdfilesystem library?

Comment: Yes there is. `FILE*` is a very big object and it eat's you RAM very fast.

Comment: Do you actually need to have them open together? Can't you open each file opportunistically, just when it's needed?

Comment: Hi @MatteoItalia, unfortunately I would then need to open and close files whilst still sending audio data to my codec board in an interrupt routine.  Opening a file will prevent the code going to the interrupt routine (as far as I remember).

Answer (score 0):

Reading through the code of the [FATFileSystem](https://os.mbed.com/teams/mbed-official/code/FATFileSystem/file/28e685e5ff7f/FATFileSystem.cpp/) library, there is no limit, unless you run out of memory. That could be the case.

Note that Mbed OS 5 has [native support](https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v5.11/apis/sdblockdevice.html) for mounting SD cards and FAT file system, so you should probably use that over the SDFileSystem library. The latter has not been updated in 2 years, while the new libraries receive regular updates.

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks for the pointer - will these new libraries enable me to open more than 11 .wav files at once?

Comment: Probably not, because I suspect it's running out of memory. Use the [heap stats](https://os.mbed.com/blog/entry/Tracking-memory-usage-with-Mbed-OS/) in Mbed OS to see current memory usage.

Comment: Hi Jan - would using LittleFileSystem allow me to open up more .wav files at once?